# How to auto activate Autofac component on creating of Owner lifetimescope?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

Imagine I have the following registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<ContactsManager>().InstancePerOwned<IDialPad>();
```

When I create `Owned<IDialpad>` no class resolved in IDialPad scope depends on ContactsManager so ContactsManager is not created. But still I want it to be created on scope creation.

When I do like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ContactsManager>().InstancePerOwned<IDialPad>().AutoActivate();
```

It's activated not on scope creation but on Autofac container build and of course it fails to activate.

I know that if i add even fake dependency to ContactsManager to any class in the scope than ContactsManager will be created automatically. But that's not what I want.

Comment: Could you describe your scenario ? It may help us finding alternative solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see many ways to doi what you want.

1. If you can modify the `IDialpad` registration, you can use the `OnActivated` event.

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
          .As<IFoo>()
          .InstancePerOwned<IBar>();
   builder.RegisterType<Bar>()
          .As<IBar>()
          .OnActivated(e => e.Context.Resolve<IFoo>());
   ```
2. If you don't have access to this registration, you can do a module that will do the same.

   ```
   class TestModule : Module
   {
       protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
           IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
           IComponentRegistration registration)
       {
           if (registration.Services
                 .Any(s => s is IServiceWithType 
                           && ((IServiceWithType)s).ServiceType == typeof(IBar)))
           {
               registration.Activated += (sender, e) =>
               {
                   e.Context.Resolve<IFoo>();
               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Based on the previous solution, you can provide a new type of service that will indicate *Autofac* to activate the specified service when another one is activated.

   The final registration will look like this :

   ```
       ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
       builder.RegisterModule(new AutoActivateModule());
       builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
               .As<IFoo>()
               .As(AutoActivateService.From<IBar>())
               .InstancePerOwned<IBar>();
       builder.RegisterType<Bar>()
               .As<IBar>();
   ```

   Code for `AutoActivateService` and `AutoActivate` will be the following :

   ```
   public class AutoActivateModule : Module
   {
       protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
           IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
           IComponentRegistration registration)
       {
           foreach (IServiceWithType typedService in registration.Services.OfType<IServiceWithType>())
           {
               registration.Activated += (sender, e) =>
               {
                   Service autoActivateService = AutoActivateService.From(typedService.ServiceType);
                   foreach (IComponentRegistration r in componentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(autoActivateService))
                   {
                       e.Context.ResolveComponent(r, new Parameter[0]);
                   }
               };
           }
       }
   }

   public class AutoActivateService : Service, IEquatable<AutoActivateService>
   {

       public static AutoActivateService From<T>()
       {
           return new AutoActivateService(typeof(T));
       }
       public static AutoActivateService From(Type targetType)
       {
           return new AutoActivateService(targetType);
       }


       private AutoActivateService(Type targetType)
       {
           this._targetType = targetType;
       }


       private readonly Type _targetType;


       public override String Description
       {
           get { return this.ToString(); }
       }
       public Type TargetType
       {
           get
           {
               return this._targetType;
           }
       }


       public Boolean Equals(AutoActivateService other)
       {
           return other != null
                  && this._targetType == other._targetType;
       }
       public override Boolean Equals(Object obj)
       {
           return this.Equals(obj as AutoActivateService);
       }
       public override Int32 GetHashCode()
       {
           return this._targetType.GetHashCode();
       }
       public override String ToString()
       {
           return String.Format("Autoactivate service for {0}", this._targetType);
       }
   }
   ```
4. You can also use the `BeginLifetimeScope` event.

   When a `Owned<T>` service is activated a new `ILifetimeScope` will be created and its tag will be the associated service.

   ```
   container.ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning += ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning;

   // ...

   private static void ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning(
       Object sender, LifetimeScopeBeginningEventArgs e)
   {
       e.LifetimeScope.ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning += ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning;

       IServiceWithType typedService = e.LifetimeScope.Tag as IServiceWithType;
       if (typedService != null && typedService.ServiceType == typeof(IBar))
       {
           e.LifetimeScope.Resolve<IFoo>();
       }
   }
   ```